# How do I overwrite certain conditions when you have two CSS files?

Tags: css, stylesheet, overwrite

I have a page called index.html and about.html.  I have a css file called main.css (it's used on every single page because of common css styles) and another called about.css (it holds styles unique to about.html).

On main.css I have this css block:

```
html, body, form {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is creating issues on about.html.  In about.css, what can I do so that the html, body, form on that page doesn't use margin: 0px;, padding: 0px;, and height: 100%?

**Question:**

Essentially, how do I prevent    html, body, form {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
from showing up on about.html? What values can I use so that margin, padding, and height essentially don't exist on about.html

Comment: you could add an `id` to your body

Comment: use a specific css classes to the new elements in the new page

Comment: @krishna i know that.  I am simply asking how to get rid of those properties with !important.

Comment: Yeah, use !important to override. @starbucks

Comment: @eshelborn my question is what values do i use to prevent them from affecting about.html? Do i set them to none? I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @starbucks there is only 1 way to override !important as far as I know. Its using !important again. Its a vicious cycle. Unless you decide to remove its initial usage you're stuck with using multiple of them to override. And ending up with !important for all of 'em.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things at play here. One, CSS is cascading - meaning if a style exists after another style with the same selectors, the latter will take precedence. If you load a stylesheet after your main.css in the DOM, any styles with the same selectors (exactly as they are in the main.css) will overwrite each other:

```
<link href="blah/main.css" ... />
<link href="blah/overwrite.css" ... />
```

Second, there is the problem of specificity. Say you have the same element targeted like so:

```
.main .last .element { //css }
.main .element { //css }
```

Even though the second set of styles are after the first, the first will take precedence because it targets the element more specifically.

The `!important` modifier is really only for global changes, which is why people tell you to use it with caution - because if EVERYTHING is `!important`, nothing is.

**In your specific case:**

Try adding a class on the about us page html element like so:

```
<html class="about-us">
```

And then target the about us page in your main.css file like so:

```
html.about-us,
body.about-us,
form.about-us { margin: auto; padding: auto; height: auto; }
```

This takes advantage of the specificity of your selector and overwrites the styles.

Comment: Thanks but my question is what values to use to prevent them from affecting about.html? So what value can i use in margin, height, padding so that it's set to none when it's on about.css?

Answer (score 2):

If you write any rules after the common CSS stylesheet is loaded it will override the common styles.

e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="about.css"/><!-- these "override" the ones in common -->
<style>
    html, body, form {
       padding:12px;
       background:blue;
       border:3px;
       /*Set whatever properties you want*/
    }
</style>
```

note I've shown the properties inline and linked...

note 2.  Just because you can do this, be weary of constantly resetting properties... you want to minimize this as much as possible.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned, I can't use inline css.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on the HTML tag and try this CSS:

```
html.class,html.class body,html.class form {
    /*Set whatever properties you want*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of a style, but you can override it as long as your "about.css" stylesheet loads after the main stylesheet.

And while you can't get rid of a style once defined, you can sometimes reset a value to whatever its default would be. For instance, "margin:auto;" will cause the margin to revert to whatever it normally would be for html, body and form.